# Maven compile trying to download my JAR from central repository

Tags: maven, pom.xml

I'm trying to use a Maven dependency that is from one of my own JAR files, not from any central repository.  So first of course I install.

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=../lib/gibson.jar -DgroupId=com.myorg -DartifactId=gibson -Dversion=22.6.0 -Dpackaging=JAR -DpomFile=pom.xml
```

Add the dependency into my project's POM.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.myorg</groupId>
        <artifactId>gibson</artifactId>
        <version>22.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Try to do a Maven compile.

> mvn compile -U

But then I get this

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ----------------------< com.myorg:-scheduler >-----------------------
[INFO] Building scheduler 1.0
[INFO] --------------------------------[ war ]---------------------------------
Downloading from spring-releases: https://repo.spring.io/release/com/myorg/gibson/22.6.0/gibson-22.6.0.jar
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/myorg/gibson/22.6.0/gibson-22.6.0.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  2.351 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-05-24T14:55:08-05:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project orbit-scheduler: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.myorg:orbit-scheduler:war:1.0: Could not find artifact com.myorg:gibson:jar:22.6.0 in spring-releases (https://repo.spring.io/release) -> [Help 1]
```

I figure that the problem lies within those two lines that start with "Downloading from..."  Of course it's not finding the artifacts there.  So why is it looking there?

The JAR files do exist on the file system though, at **/home/jenkins/.m2/repository/com/myorg/gibson/22.6.0**  So how do I get Maven to look for them there?  I read about the  tag and I think that's the solution.  I know the general format is something like:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>some id</id>
        <name>some user friendly name</name>
        <url>some url</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

But I cannot figure out what I should put in there.  I think ID and Name are just values I make up myself?  What's the URL?  We have a BitBucket repository.  Do I use that?  It just now occurred to me to try that so I'll give that a try and update later with my results.

Here is the full POM

> xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
> xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
> xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 [https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">](https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd%22%3E)
> 4.0.0
>
> org.springframework.boot
> spring-boot-starter-parent
> 2.5.5
>  
>
> com.myorg
> scheduler
> 1.0
> war
> scheduler
> scheduler
>
> <java.version>1.8</java.version>
> <repackage.classifier/>
> <spring-native.version>0.10.4</spring-native.version>
> com.myorg.scheduler.SchedulerApplication
>
> ```
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
>         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
>         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
>         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-quartz</artifactId>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
>         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
>         <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
>         <scope>runtime</scope>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
>         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
>         <scope>provided</scope>
>     </dependency>
>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
>         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
>         <scope>test</scope>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>xerces</groupId>
>         <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
>         <version>2.9.1</version>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>xalan</groupId>
>         <artifactId>xalan</artifactId>
>         <version>2.7.1</version>
>     </dependency>
>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>javax</groupId>
>         <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
>         <version>8.0</version>
>         <scope>provided</scope>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>javax.json</groupId>
>         <artifactId>javax.json-api</artifactId>
>         <version>1.1</version>
>     </dependency>
>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
>         <artifactId>javax.json</artifactId>
>         <version>1.1</version>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.jdom</groupId>
>         <artifactId>jdom</artifactId>
>         <version>1.1</version>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
>         <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
>         <version>3.2.2</version>
>     </dependency>
>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>jboss</groupId>
>         <artifactId>jboss-client</artifactId>
>         <version>4.0.2</version>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>jboss</groupId>
>         <artifactId>jboss-javaee</artifactId> <!--jboss-javaee.jar-->
>         <version>4.2.3</version>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>jboss</groupId>
>         <artifactId>jboss-remoting</artifactId> <!-- jboss-remoting.jar-->
>         <version>jboss-5.1.0</version>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>jboss</groupId>
>         <artifactId>jboss-security-spi</artifactId> <!--jboss-security-spi.jar -->
>         <version>2.0.1</version>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>jboss</groupId>
>         <artifactId>jboss-serialization</artifactId> <!--jboss-serialization.jar -->
>         <version>jboss-5.1.0</version>
>     </dependency>
>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>jboss</groupId>
>         <artifactId>jboss-common-core</artifactId> <!--jboss-common-core.jar-->
>         <version>2.2.0</version>
>     </dependency>
>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>jboss</groupId>
>         <artifactId>jbosssx-client</artifactId> <!--jbosssx-client.jar-->
>         <version>4.2.3</version>
>     </dependency>
>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>jboss</groupId>
>         <artifactId>jnp-client</artifactId>
>         <version>4.2.2.GA</version>
>     </dependency>
>
>
>      <dependency>
>         <groupId>com.myorg</groupId>
>         <artifactId>gibson</artifactId>
>         <version>22.6.0</version>
>     </dependency>
>
> </dependencies>
>
>
>
> <build>
>     <plugins>
>         <plugin>
>             <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
>             <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
>         </plugin>
>         <plugin>
>             <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
>             <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
>             <configuration>
>                 <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
>             </configuration>
>         </plugin>
>
>
>     </plugins>
> </build>
>
>     <repositories>
>     <repository>
>         <id>spring-releases</id>
>         <name>Spring Releases</name>
>         <url>https://repo.spring.io/release</url>
>         <snapshots>
>             <enabled>true</enabled>
>         </snapshots>
>     </repository>
> </repositories>
>
> <pluginRepositories>
>     <pluginRepository>
>         <id>spring-releases</id>
>         <name>Spring Releases</name>
>         <url>https://repo.spring.io/release</url>
>         <snapshots>
>             <enabled>true</enabled>
>         </snapshots>
>     </pluginRepository>
> </pluginRepositories> </project>
> ```

Comment: First: Why do you have defined the spring repositories in your pom file? All releases are available from central repository. In other words you can remove those parts from your pom file...furthermore does the artifact `com.myorg` coming from another maven project?

Comment: The thing with the Spring repositories was part of my desperation at figuring out the problem.  I'm kind of a beginner at Maven and don't understand a lot beyond the putting in dependencies from the central repositories.  I have had that part commented out for most of my development and still got these same problems.

Artifact com.myorg does indeed come from another Maven project.

Comment: If this artifact `com.myorg` is coming from an Maven project you can do that simply via `mvn install` in the appropriate project not needed to do such complex callings via `install-file`etc.. afterwards you should be able to consume that...furthermore it might be a better idea to create a multi module build which contains your `com.myorg` plus your current project..which would solve the whole issue...